# Defining a range despite C++ rounding errors

Tags: c++, rounding-error

Given a lower bound, upper bound, and step, I would like to create a vector that lists containing numbers that start at the lower bound, and step up to the higher bound, separated by the step.
e.g. lower = 1.5, upper = 6.0, step = 1.0: 
return [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5].

My code in C++ is currently:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

vec createArray( double lower, double upper, double step) {

    int arrayLength = int ((upper - lower)/step + 1);
    vec array(arrayLength);
    for( int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j += 1 )
    {
        array(j) = lower + j*step;
    }
    return array;
}
```

It ideally should work fine, but rounding errors keep making it output the wrong things. For example,

```
int((pow(10,-7)-0)/pow(10,-9));
```

will sometimes output 99 and not 100, presumably because 10^-7 is being represented as 9.9999...9*10^-8.

I was wondering, is there some kind of method or trick that can help me avoid these problems?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Use methods like floor(), ceil(), round() or C++ equivalents. And maybe add tolerances, relative in size to the bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this would be more straight forward to do with a `std::vector` and a `for` loop.

```
std::vector<double> createArray(double lower, double upper, double step)
{
    std::vector<double> values;
    for (double value = lower; value <= upper; value += step)
    {
        values.push_back(value);
    }
    return values;
}
```

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/2pbu)

This will keep the *actual values* as close as possible to the correct floating point value without accumulating rounding errors. You can still output the values to your preferred precision using the `<iomanip>` library.

Comment: Or use C++11 range-based for, maybe combined with lambdas.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Sure, there are slicker ways to do this, I was just trying to get the idea across. Probably a combination of `std::iota` with a `std::back_inserter` could do the trick.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Neither are appropriate for this code sample.

Comment: @remyabel. I disagree. Care to elaborate on why neither would be appropriate?

Comment: @ErikAlapää A range-based for loop is typically used to iterate over an container with populated elements, since it is just syntactic sugar that uses the containers `begin()` and `end()` to avoid having to a make an iterator variable just for looping. If you want to populate a container, there would be nothing for the range-based for loop to iterate over. Similarly a `lambda` is typically used in place of a functor. I'm not sure what you had in mind for using a `lambda`, I'm sure there could be some use case.

Comment: @ErikAlapää He's not operating over a range, so a **range**-based for loop doesn't make sense. There's also no need for a function object here.

Comment: Actually, I wrote too quickly, you are at least partially right. Range-based for is not so useful here since we are creating a vectorl, not modifying it. But a lambda may still be useful to construct the elements and take care of the floating-point problems.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of truncating, you should [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) the result. This would at least work as long as your integers are exactly representable in your floating point type.

Answer (score 1):

Using a vector, you don't need to have the size of the container before hand. So just create a loop that stops when you have exceeded your max value. Here's some pseudo code.

```
vector<double> createVector(double minVal, double maxVal, double step)
{
    vector<double> data;

    while(minVal < maxVal){  
       data.push_back(minVal);   
       minVal += step;
    }

      return data;
}
```